# Angular 8: ERROR TypeError: "ptf.getCompositeKey is not a function"

Tags: angular

I have an Angular class to map JSON objects sent from an API. It works, but when I call a method defined in the class, Angular does not recognize class function as a function.

```
ptf.getCompositeKey()
```

I've tried changing it to static method.

```
export class PartialTeamFeature extends TeamFeature {
  id: number;
  teamFeatureOID?: string;
  scrumTeam?: DbScrumTeam; 
  sprint?: DbIteration; 
  estimatedTime?: number;

  TeamFeature: TeamFeature;
  ScrumTeam: ScrumTeam;

  // fields that have to be figured out in fr
  ParentTeamFeature?: TeamFeature;

  getCompositeKey(): string {
    return this.teamFeatureOID.toString() + this.scrumTeam.id.toString();
  }
}
```

The linter says it recognizes the function, but the browser does not.
`ERROR TypeError: "ptf.getCompositeKey is not a function"`

Can you explain why and how to make the function visible? So far, I have to put the function in a component to use it.

Comment: Where are how is `ptf` defined ?

Comment: I define it in a component `ptf : PartialTeamFeature;` and it is mapped in a `subscribe()` method. When I log to the console, it shows all the ptf properties exist. None of them is undefined or null.

Comment: Can you please post the code.

Comment: Have you instantiated the class where it's used? I mean `let ptf = new PartialTeamFeature();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `ptf : PartialTeamFeature;` that just means that ptf is of type `PartialTeamFeature`.

In order to assign a value to ptf you need to do :

```
let ptf = new PartialTeamFeature();
```

now you should be able to access the objects/methods available on ptf

Comment: Yeah, looks like Angular `subscribe()` method applies the properties from the JSON to the class, but not the methods. Is there a way to make `subscribe()` make a `PartialTeamFeature` instance so I have access to the instance methods?

Comment: Yes you can specify return type to be of type `PartialTeamFeature` and be able to use the instance methods, can you show some code and how you subscribe to it? It's difficult to answer if no details are available